# Change main price when add to cart using opencart2.3

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.3

I have OpenCart v2.3 and I need make customize on product details page.

**Explain what I need:**

- The product take price from the admin panel by default.
- I need add custom price when user click add to cart button.

**Explain how OpenCart adds product to cart:**

- When user click on add to cart button, `ajaxFunction` is called and goes to `checkout/cart/add` function with all input fields.
- Inside function `add()` in cart controller

  $this->cart->add($this->request->post['product_id'], $quantity, $option, $recurring_id);

And `system/library/cart/cart.php` contains all functions

How can apply this idea?

Answer (score 0):

> "How can apply this idea?"

With difficulty, because it will affect a lot of parts of the system.

Perhaps you should consider having a second copy of the product with a different price and your code adjusts just the template so that clicking "Add to Cart" actually adds the second product instead.